# Unable to install postgres with python3 support on mac

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython

Both `postgres` and `python3` are already installed on my `High Sierra` system - so the following was attempted:

```
brew upgrade  postgres --with-python
```

I had thought that the `--with-python` would have installed *just the postgres plpython3u language support* . However it tried to [re]install python itself.

```
  /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.26.0: 11 files, 3.7MB
==> Installing postgresql dependency: python
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/python-3.7.2.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring python-3.7.2.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /usr/local/opt/python3
Error: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /usr/local/opt/python3
```

Then when attempting to load the `plpython3u` we see:

```
19:44:24/sbgmaster2 $psql
psql (10.3)
Type "help" for help.

myuser=# CREATE LANGUAGE plpython3u;
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/plpython3": No such file or directory
```

So how can `plpyton3u` be installed then?

Note: this is about *programming* (*on topic*) because this is for using *UDF*'s - `user defined functions` that are purely for programming.